# blocking android to be used with one app

Tags: android

I have an app to be used in a public site and I would like to block device so users can not to play around with other apps in device.

Iphone has this feature called Guided access. Is there something similar for Android?

The problem is the three buttons (home, back and apps running buttons)

Comment: I didn't notice that term to this problem. Thank you!